# Every proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ is of the form $\left\langle \, \overline{\frac{1}{p^n}} \, \right\rangle$ for some $n>0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $\displaystyle \mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})=\bigcup_{n>0} \left\langle \, \overline{\frac{1}{p^n}} \, \right\rangle$. Show the following:

a) Every proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ is of the form $\displaystyle \left\langle \, \overline{\frac{1}{p^n}} \, \right\rangle$ for some $n>0$.

b) The multiplication map $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty}) \to \mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ by $p^t$ is a surjective group homomorphism. Also find the kernel of this map.

I have noted that if $z \in \mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$, then $z=a/p^m$ for some $m>0$. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Hint for a): first show the result for every *cyclic* subgroup. Deduce that every proper subgroup cannot contain any $a$ of $p$-adic valuation too low, ie is contained in some $\langle \overline{p^{-k}}\rangle$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ large enough. Please make explicit what the overline means for b), is $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ a subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}$ or a subgroup of (say) $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @Mindlack The overline for $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ is $\mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$? Why is it enough to show the result for cyclic subgroup in part (a)?

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\bar{x}$ denotes the residue class of $x \in \Bbb Q$ modulo $\Bbb Z \unlhd \Bbb Q$.

---

Assume that $H \lneq \Bbb Z(p^\infty).$ For $t \ge 0$, define $\Bbb Z(p^t) = \left\langle \overline{\dfrac{1}{p^t}} \right\rangle.$ Note that

$$\Bbb Z(p^0) \subset \Bbb Z(p^1) \subset \Bbb Z(p^2) \subset \cdots$$

and

$$\Bbb Z(p^\infty) = \bigcup_{t \ge 0}\Bbb Z(p^t).$$

Note that $\Bbb Z(p^0)$ is the trivial group and hence $\Bbb Z(p^0) \le H.$ Now, since $H \lneq \Bbb Z(p^\infty),$ there is some $t \ge 0$ such that $\Bbb Z(p^{t+1}) \not\subseteq H$. Fix the smallest such $t$.

Thus, we have $\Bbb Z(p^t) \subset H$. We now show the reverse inclusion.
For the sake of contradiction, assume that there exists $x \in H \setminus\Bbb Z(p^t)$. Then, $$x = \overline{\dfrac{r}{p^m}}$$
for some $r \in \Bbb N,$ $m \ge 0$ with $\gcd(r, p) = 1.$ However, note that since $x \notin \Bbb Z(p^t)$, we have $m \ge t + 1$.

Now, by [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity), there exist integers $a, b$ such that $$ar + bp^m = 1 \quad\text{or}\quad a\frac{r}{p^m} + b = \frac{1}{p^m}.$$
Going modulo $\Bbb Z$ shows that $$\overline{\frac{1}{p^m}} = a\overline{\frac{r}{p^m}} \in \left\langle \overline{\frac{r}{p^m}} \right\rangle = \langle x \rangle \subset H.$$

But the above contradicts that $\Bbb Z(p^{t + 1}) \not\subset H$.

Thus, we get that $H = \Bbb Z(p^t)$.

---

**An aside.** The above shows that all the proper subgroups of $\Bbb Z(p^\infty)$ are finite. In particular, all descending chains of subgroups stabilise. This shows that $\Bbb Z(p^\infty)$ is an Artinian $\Bbb Z$-module. However, the chain $$\Bbb Z(p^0) \subsetneq \Bbb Z(p^1) \subsetneq \Bbb Z(p^2) \subsetneq \cdots$$ shows that it is not Noetherian.

---

---

Showing that the map is subjective should not be too difficult. Forgetting the residue classes for a moment, think about dividing by $p^t$ in $\Bbb Q$. Conclude from there.
Now, note that the kernel is not the whole group, since the map is subjective. Thus, the kernel is of the form $\Bbb Z(p^n)$. Now you can just check for the largest $n$ such that $\overline{\dfrac{1}{p^n}} \mapsto 0.$

Comment: Why is the following true? "since $H \lneq G,$ there is some $t \ge 0$ such that $\Bbb Z(p^{t+1}) \not\subseteq H$."

Comment: Think about it. If there were no such $t$, then you'd have $\Bbb Z(p^{t + 1}) \subset H$ for all $t \ge 0$. But then their union (over all $t$) must be in $H$, the union being...?

Comment: Oh but I never defined $G$. Hopefully, it was clear that I meant $\Bbb Z(p^\infty)$. I have edited that now.

Comment: Everything is clear now. Thank you. But, I have not studied modules.

Comment: That is okay. The "Aside" was meant as an additional piece of information for those who do know modules. Maybe it will make sense to you at a later point of time (if and) when you study it. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by check for the largest $n$ such that $\overline{\frac{1}{p^n}} \to 0$?

Comment: By $x \mapsto 0$, I mean that $x$ is in the kernel. That is, find the largest $n$ such that the element written gets mapped to $0$ under the given map.

Comment: Still not sure what you mean?

Comment: How do we show that the multiplication map is a homomorphism?

Comment: Let $\varphi$ denote the multiplication map mentioned in part (b). I am asking you to find the largest $n$ such that $\varphi(\overline{p^{-n}}) = 0$.

Comment: To see that the multiplication map is a homomorphism, use the distributivity of multiplication over addition. By the way, note that the map should be multiplication by $\overline{p^t}$, not by $p^t$.

Comment: Can you explain in some details, perhaps by including it in your answer.

Comment: I don't think that I will do that. Showing that it is a homomorphism is something you should work out by yourself. Check the definition and see what it means for $\varphi$ to be a homomorphism.

Comment: What is the difference between multiplication by $\overline{p^t}$ and $p^t$?

Comment: $p^t$ is not an element of $\Bbb Z(p^\infty)$, so it does not make sense in this context to multiply by that.